# Javascript to get Current Date irrespective of Time Zone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I am looking for javascript code which will give me 1st date of the current month according to local timezone (client browser timezone).

Currently I am using the code below:

```
var startDate =new Date (2012,5,1);
```

Which correctly  gives me this value:

> Fri Jun 1 00:00:00 EDT 2012

But when I try the same thing in a browser in Beirut, which is +2.00 GMT, it gives May 31st "at times" (meaning if I try in the morning it gives me 31st but Beriut PM time works fine)

Basically I need to get a local browser current 1st date. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) function without parameters, always return the current time for the browser, which takes the time and timezone from the OS.

Try this:

```
var now = new Date(),
    first = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1);
alert(first);
```

​
You can try to see the time zone using `now.getTimezoneOffset();`

Comment: Thanks Martin, Esailija for inputs, this worked well and cleared my concpets as well..